# Is there an (idiomatic or any other) way to pass in additional context/state to the UnmarshalJSON([]byte) interface implementation for nested structs?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling, goroutine

I have the following structure in my application

```
 // foo.go
type FooList struct {
    Fools []*foo `json:"list"`
    // maybe
    Req *http.Request
}

type Foo struct {
    //...
    //...
}

func (f *Foo) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // need access to request.Context here
    // or request scoped state, how?
    // is it possible to access FooList.Req?
}

// handler.go
func handleSomething(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    //...
    // some additional work happens in goroutines - a few can be started up
    go func(r *http.Request) {
        fools := &fooList{Req: r} // could have a field here for r, but how can the nested struct access it?
        // call a service that returns a foo list and decode
        resp, err = httpClient.Do(...)
        err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&fools) // triggers custom unmarshalling, needs "r"
        //  ...
        //  ...
    }(r)

    //...
    // ...
}
```

I hope what I am doing is not too cryptic and is fairly understandable. My HTTP request handler relies on an external service for some data (returned as a JSON) that can be deserialized. During this process, I would like to use a custom unmarshaller to affect the resulting instance states and I need the incoming request context (for example) to be available to the UnmarshalJSON() function.

Is this possible? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You could do something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/psxFJSszPXI), although it doesn't look too good to me and I'd avoid this kind of design if possible.

Comment: I solved my use case using the example provided by @mkopriva. I agree that it does not look elegant but I cannot see why the design is particularly bad. Since I have a few levels of nesting it was a question of passing the required field to the "child" structs when they are initialized in ```UnmarshalJSON()```

Answer (score 3):

> Is this possible?

No.

> Am I missing something obvious?

No.

Go is basically magic free. If you want something to be done you have to do it like you did. (I would use only the Context instead of the whole Request and use an unexported field.)

Comment: Thanks. To clarify my question further, is it possible for the inner Foo (from my example) to access the top-level structs' fields inside Foo's own UnmarshalJSON() method?